# Ansible: Run new playbook from task

Tags: display, ansible

> Let assume following:

main-playbook.yml

```
- name: Play-1
  hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  gather_facts: no
  roles:
    - role: my-role
      vars:
        newhost: 192.168.1.1
```

generated_playbook.yml

```
- name: Play-1
  hosts: newhost
  gather_facts: yes
  
  tasks:
  - name: Task1
  - name: Task2
  - name: Task3
```

main task from the Role:

```
- name: "Role MAIN-1"
  add_host:
    name: newhost
    ansible_host: "{{newhost}}"

- include: generated_playbook.yml
```

Error:

```
ERROR! conflicting action statements: hosts, tasks

The error appears to be in 'generated_playbook.yml': line 1, column 3, but may
be elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.

The offending line appears to be:

- name: Generated Playbook
  ^ here
```

I create new role and include this role in the main playbook.
In this role I add new host to in-memory inventory and than, I generate new playbook with j2 template example output generated_playbook.yml

Question:
Is there a way to run this new generated playbook only on the new added host but not adding anything else to main playbook? 
I was trying to use import-playbook or include inside the role but this fails

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not possible. Quoting from [ansible.builtin.import_playbook](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/import_playbook_module.html#synopsis)

> Files with a list of plays can only be included at the top level.

The [example](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/import_playbook_module.html#examples) explicitly shows this

```yaml
- name: This DOES NOT WORK
  hosts: all
  tasks:
    - debug:
        msg: task1

    - name: This fails because I'm inside a play already
      import_playbook: stuff.yaml
```

---

**Notes**

- There is no *include_playbook*. See what *include_** and *import_** modules are available.

```bsh
shell> ansible-doc -t module -l | grep include_

include_role    Load and ...  
include_tasks   Dynamically inclu...
include_vars    Load variables from files, dynamically...
```

```bsh
shell> ansible-doc -t module -l | grep import_

import_playbook Imp...        
import_role     Import a ro...
import_tasks    Impo...
```

- Quoting note from *import_module*:

> This is a core feature of Ansible, rather than a module, and cannot be overridden like a module.